# java loses values from ManagedBeans

Tags: java, jsf, managed-bean

I try to write an application to create PDF files, it uses the JavaServer Faces. I struggle with a problem when I give the value of the text box from bean to factory class, the values ​​are lost. I wonder why this happens, already tried many solutions, but they will cause expansion of the code and do not help.

Bean code:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class PanelInneBean extends AbstractPanel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final int CODE = 4;
    private boolean use;
    private String tytul, opis;
    private PdfFactory pdf = PdfFactory.getPdfObject();

    public PanelInneBean() {
    use = false;
    }

    public boolean getUse() {
    return use;
    }

    public String getTytul() {
    return tytul;
    }

    public void setTytul(String tytul) {
    this.tytul = tytul;
    }

    public String getOpis() {
    return opis;
    }

    public void setOpis(String opis) {
    this.opis = opis;
    }

    public int getCode() {
    return CODE;
    }

    private void add() {
    use = true;
    }

    public void addBean() {
    add();
    pdf.addElement(this);
    System.out.println("InnePanel after pdf.addElement() this.opis:" + this.opis);
    // This sysout prints the correct value after give object to factory
    }
}
```

Factory piece of code:

```
  public int addElement(PdfElement element) {
    pdfType = true;
    if (element.getUse()) {
        elementList.add(element);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
    }

    public void prepare() {
    for (PdfElement element : elementList) {
        System.out.println("element.code:" + element.getCode());
        switch (element.getCode()) {
        case 0:
        if (nF != null)
            break;
        nF = new NaglowekFactory(element, Counter.getNumber());
        break;
        case 1:
        if (pF != null)
            break;
        pF = new ProduktyFactory(element, Counter.getNumber());
        prodSum = pF.getProdukty().getSuma();
        euroData = pF.getProdukty().getEuroData();
        break;
        case 2:
        if (mF != null)
            break;
        mF = new MontazFactory(element, Counter.getNumber());
        servSum = mF.getMontaz().getSuma();
        break;
        case 3:
        if (uF != null)
            break;
        uF = new UslugiFactory(element, Counter.getNumber());
        asmSum = uF.getUslugi().getSuma();
        break;
        case 4:
        if (iF != null)
            break;
        iF = new InneFactory(element, Counter.getNumber());
            //here Opis value is empty
        break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("factory.prepare() ->");
    }
```

Constructor of `InneFactory:`

```
    PanelInneBean inne;

public InneFactory(PdfElement element, int order) {
    inne = (PanelInneBean) element;
    System.out.println("innerFactory constructor, inne.getTytul(): "
        + inne.getTytul());

        //here values are empty

    this.order = order;
    list = new ArrayList<Element>();
}

public int getOrder() {
    return order;
}
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are running into a common misconception about how `@ViewScoped` beans really work.  The bean object itself is created on every Faces request and destroyed after every Faces response.

After the bean is re created however JSF will enter the first lifecycle phase **RestoreView**.  During this phase it will fetch the last good values for this bean from the View State and apply them to the beans Managed Properties.

Basically what is happening is that you are invoking an action, which generates a seperate request than the one that loaded the page, and at this point the reference you added to the `PdfFactory` is now lost because the PdfFactory in the last object was destroyed!

The best way to resolve this would be to make `PdfFactory` a Managed Bean.  You can initialize the factory in the `@PostConstruct` method and you can inject other Managed Beans into your PdfFactory bean using the `@ManagedProperty` annotation.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public PdfFactory extends ... implements Serializable {

  @ManagedProperty("#{myViewBean}")
  private MyViewBean viewBean;

  @PostConstruct
  public initializeFactory() {
    //Do stuff
  }

  public void prepare() {
    // prepare stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: what when I have couple of ManagedBeans sending data to factory? Just add them to @ManagedProperty?

Comment: @insict You can yeah... there a number of ways you can do this, just realizing though that your factory should be a ManagedBean of some kind with some kind of scope.  Creating the Factory object on object creation is why you are losing the data.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I have one more question for You, (or someone else) Factory class have private Classes inside, like `OtherFactory ` which has proper ManagedBean object (`Other`). how should I use the annotation @ ManagedProperty `OtherFactory` creating an object or inside `OtherFactory` to create specific object `Other`?

Comment: @insict Hmmm I am not sure to be honest.  I have never tried to merge the Factory pattern with the Managed Bean (View Controller pattern).  Perhaps you have to reconsider your design... or perhaps just make PdfFactory `@ApplicationScoped` and treat it like a Singleton?  Then all you have to do is reference PdfFactory as a ManagedProperty in all of your views.